# How to add a div on a specifix top and left posiion to another div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position, appendto

How can i set a child div to **x px left** and **y px top** when adding to another div

**HTML**

```
<div id="divContainer"> </div>
```

**Script**

```
 $.get(target, function (data) {
        $(data).appendTo('#divContainer').css( { left:100,top:200});               
  });
```

The get request will give me the markup for another div.

This does not work for me ( positioning to left and top). Any thoughts ?

Comment: Do you have `divContainer` set with `position:relative;` and the data you're adding set with `position:absolute;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the `position` as well.

```
$(data).appendTo('#divContainer').css( {position: "absolute",left:100,top:200});
```

By default, a `div` has a position of `static`.  `top` and `left` do not affect elements with static position.